# Soft question - are these two set notations correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, notation

Do these sets equal the interval notation given?
\begin{align}
T&=\{t\in \mathbb{R}:t^2\lt{2}\}=(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})\\
S&=\{s\in \mathbb{R}:s^2\leq{2}\}=[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]
\end{align}

Comment: Are you asking if the idea that $T=S$ correct, or that the sets equal the interval notation given?

Comment: Do the sets equal the interval notation. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the two statements are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the sets do indeed equal the interval notation given.

You can sort of analogize why to when you solved inequalities in grade school:

$$x^2 < 2 \implies \left\{\begin{matrix}
x < \sqrt 2 \\ 
x > - \sqrt  2
\end{matrix}\right. \implies -\sqrt 2 < x < \sqrt  2 \implies x \in (-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$$

It was just always assumed back then (unless otherwise stated) $x$ was a real number. The setbuilder notation just explicitly states that (since you might not always deal with real numbers).